# Не переведен блок справки на странице Меты «Задать вопрос»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

I don't speak Russian, but I happened to see a section of this site that is still English, namely the screen you get when typing a header on Meta:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

You can of course discuss in Russian further and translate the question into Russian.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не переведен текст на странице Меты «Задать Вопрос»](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)

Comment: Thank you, this had already been reported.